# How to different views (sheets) from the same sheet in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot-table

I want to create 2 sheets in Excel where one is the mirror of the other but with different organization. 
More precisely, I have one sheet with three columns that organize items inside their categories and one column for their price, like this:

```
Category | SubCateg | Item | Price
----------------------------------
 catA    |          |      |
         |  subA1   |      |
         |          | aaa  |  80
         |          | bbb  |  100
         |  subA2   |      |
         |          | ccc  |  90
 catB    |          |      |
         |  subB1   |      |
         |          | ddd  |  100
```

I want to create another sheet with the same data but ordered by price, like this:

```
Category | SubCateg | Item | Price
----------------------------------
 catA    |          |      |
         |  subA1   |      |
         |          | bbb  |  100
 catB    |          |      |
         |  subB1   |      |
         |          | ddd  |  100
 catA    |          |      |
         |  subA2   |      |
         |          | ccc  |  90
         |  subA1   |      |
         |          | aaa  |  80
```

It doesn't necessarily need to look like this, but this ilustrates what I want.

I can't just order by price because of the categories in different columns. I also don't want to do any macro/formulas to concatenate categories+items or something like this.

I tried to make a pivot chart but I couldn't make it work, also because of the many columns to describe one item. Am I doing something wrong in the pivot chart?

Is there a better way to represent items inside categories so I could make this work better?

I also would like to make the changes made on the mirror sheet to be applied on the first, if I'm not asking too much...

Any way to make this work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to represent your data would be
catA  SubA1  aaa  80
catA  subA1  bbb  100
catA  subB1  ccc  90
catB  subB1  ddd  100

then you can sort the data, use it in a pivot table etc etc

Comment: I didn't want to repeat the category for each item, I wanted to make something that looked like a "tabbed/bullet" system.

Comment: You need to separate your reports and your data rather than duplicating your data. If you represent your data in the way I suggested you can make your reports on that data look the way you want. For instance Pivot Tables by default do not repeat the categories.

Answer (score 0):

From the tool bar DATA>SORT will so this for you.

Now to get the same sheet to display both views you can either write some VBA to set the sort criteria, or you can record a couple of macros and tack them onto a command button.

Comment: DATA>SORT wont work because of the way I organized the items into categories, and those categories are in different columns.